# GET request with Java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, http, get

I am writing a simple program to send a get request to a specific url "http://badunetworks.com/about/". The request works if I send it to "http://badunetworks.com" but I need to send it to the about page.

```
package badunetworks;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class GetRequest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        GetRequest getReq = new GetRequest();

        //Runs SendReq passing in the url and port from the command line
        getReq.SendReq("www.badunetworks.com/about/", 80);


    }

    public void SendReq(String url, int port) throws Exception {

        //Instantiate a new socket
        Socket s = new Socket("www.badunetworks.com/about/", port);

        //Instantiates a new PrintWriter passing in the sockets output stream
        PrintWriter wtr = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

        //Prints the request string to the output stream
        wtr.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
        wtr.println("Host: www.badunetworks.com");
        wtr.println("");
        wtr.flush();

        //Creates a BufferedReader that contains the server response
        BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String outStr;

        //Prints each line of the response 
        while((outStr = bufRead.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(outStr);
        }


        //Closes out buffer and writer
        bufRead.close();
        wtr.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any error output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if the about page link is about.html ,then you have change this line `wtr.println("GET / HTTP/1.1")` into `wtr.println("GET /about.html HTTP/1.1").`

in socket creation remove the /about

`wtr.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");`--->this line call the home page of the host you specified.

Answer (score 3):

When you're doing such a low-level access to a webserver, you should understand the [7 OSI layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). Socket is on layer 5 and HTTP on layer 7. That's also the reason, why [java.net.Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) only accepts host names or InetAddr and no URLs.
To do it with sockets, you have to implement the HTTP protocol properly, that is

- Create a socket connection to the *host* and *port*, i.e. `www.badunetworks.com` and `80`
- Send a HTTP packet to the outputstream containing, method, resource by *path* and protocol version, i.e. `GET /about/ HTTP/1.1`
- Read and interpret the response properly (headers and body)

But I wonder why you're doing it this complicated, there are a lot of alternatives to implementing low-level http clients yourself:

- good old [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), as deprecated as its handling is, it's still one of the easiest way to read a resource, just call `openStream()` to read it
- [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) is one of the most widely used http client implementation for java, which is quite easy to use and more flexible than the reading via URL
- [javax.ws.rs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) has a good builder api for creating web clients

Comment: Badu Networks is hiring a java programming intern and one of the things you have to do when applying for the job is complete a programming challenge. The challenge is executing a GET request using only java socket programming.

Comment: I made all the suggested changes and it seems to work now. However, I am getting a 404 response code which is strange since the path works when I type it into the browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you need open Socket to url without path e.g.

```
Socket("www.badunetworks.com", port);
```

and after send command GET /{path} HTTP/1.1 e.g.

```
GET /about HTTP/1.1
```

... other header...

Answer (score 0):

When you send a response add \n in the end

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.105", 8080);
         PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    )  {
        writer.println("GET / HTTP/1.0\n");
        String str;
        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```