# Java - Website Html extracting using Socket

Tags: java, sockets

The code below doesn't get any html from the url

```
URL url = new URL("https://google.com");
        Socket socket = new Socket(url.getHost(),443);
        socket.setSoTimeout(15000);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        String c = "";
        while((c = reader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        reader.close();
        socket.close();
```

I'm aware of URLConnection method openConnection() and URL class method openStream() but i don't want to use those. All i want to know is why i don't get any input using Socket class but i do get an input using other approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending any request. HTTP is a request-response protocol: you need to send a request telling the Web server which URL you want to retrieve, and then it will send you the data for this URL.

Comment: how can i do that using socket?

Comment: @parsa lookie here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086560/get-request-with-java-sockets

Comment: Learn about how the HTTP protocol works, find out the format of the request, and send that request through the socket. (Also you probably want to send HTTP requests to port 80, not HTTPS requests to port 443, because implementing a HTTPS handshake over raw sockets is rather non-trivial.)